# for loop in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can someone help take a look at this method and advise please.. SOmethings seems not quite right.

```
for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(_annotation2) - 5 ; i++){
    [a.annotationsPatients addObject:[_annotation2 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you think is not right?  What should it do?  What is it actually doing instead of what it should do?  Edit: Aaaaand I spotted the obvious problem.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: I've rolled back your roll back because the edits were made by the author.  Let him decide what is in his question.

Comment: @Luck Young: If you are still getting the problem, please add the declaration of the property to your question.

Comment: @Jeremy: The edit changes the question so completely that none of the supplied answers address it anymore. This is well-covered on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57867/what-to-do-when-people-change-their-questions-to-something-completely-different http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48345/what-is-the-etiquette-for-changing-the-substance-of-a-question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58504/what-should-i-do-when-a-question-keeps-getting-edited

Comment: @Josh:  I think it would be better if you had put a comment in.

Comment: @Jeremy: You make a fair point there -- I should have left a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `sizeof()` to get the number of elements in an `NSArray`. You use `count`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<[_annotation2 count] - 5 ; i++){
    [a.annotationsPatients addObject:[_annotation2 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: a.annotationsPatients = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        
    
        for(int i = 0; i< [_annotation2 count] - 5 ; i++){
            [a.annotationsPatients addObject:[_annotation2 objectAtIndex:i]];
        }   
        NSLog(@"%i", [a.annotationsPatients count]);


a.annotationsPatient still prints 0.. I dun understand is there anything wrong.

Comment: @Luck Yong, Are you sure _annotation2 has more than 5 objects? If it is less than 5, obviously [a.annotationsPatients count] will contain 0 objects.

Comment: ya i am sure.. i printed out and there were 126 objects inside =(

Comment: I am _guessing_ @Luck's got the `annotationsParent` property defined as something like `@property (copy) NSArray *annotationsParent`, since I can't really think of any other issues there'd be other than having a custom setter that doesn't work.  If that is the case, he's probably just modifying a copy of the array each loop.

Comment: The most likely cause is that a.annotationsPatients or _annoation2 is nil at this point. You say you checked _annotation2, so that leaves a.annotationsPatients.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `sizeof` incorrectly.  `sizeof` gets the size of a given data type, not the length of what I assume is an `NSArray`.  To get the length of an `NSArray`, use the `count` method, like so:

```
NSUInteger arrayLength = [someArray count];
for (int x = 0; x < arrayLength; ++x)
{
    // do whatever in here
}
```

Comment: a.annotationsPatients = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        
    
        for(int i = 0; i< [_annotation2 count] - 5 ; i++){
            [a.annotationsPatients addObject:[_annotation2 objectAtIndex:i]];
        }   
        NSLog(@"%i", [a.annotationsPatients count]);


a.annotationsPatient still prints 0.. I dun understand is there anything wrong.

Comment: You should update your question and show how the `annotationsPatients` property is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Actually "count" method is used instead of "sizeof".

Review your code as below:

```
for(int i = 0; i<[_annotation2 count] - 5 ; i++){
    [a.annotationsPatients addObject:[_annotation2 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: plz take a look at my edited codes. i tried yours but is stil printing 0... =(

Comment: Hi, Please make sure that, count for _annotation2 should be more than 5. Please check it and let me know in case of any difficulty.